# Por que o $routeParams não está trazendo o id?

Tags: angularjs

Estou usando $routeParams.idunidade para trazer de outra tela o id de uma unidade mas o idunidade é sempre "undefined" e eu não to conseguindo entender o porque, pois já usei isso e sempre funcionou! Será que a forma de uso mudou?

Segue meus códigos:

```
<div class="row corpo">
    <div class="col-ms-12 exibeUnidades">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="200"><b>Unidade</b></td>
                    <td width="200"><b>Endereço</b></td>
                    <td width="200"><b>Bairro</b></td>
                    <td width="100"><b>Cidade</b></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="u in unidades">
                    <td>{{u.unidade}}</td>
                    <td>{{u.endereco}}, {{u.numero}}</td>
                    <td>{{u.bairro}}</td>
                    <td>{{u.cidade}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#/unidade-editar/{{u.idunidade}}">editar</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("UnidadeEditarCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, $routeParams) {

$scope.idempresa = localStorage.getItem('domanda_idempresa');
$scope.empresa = localStorage.getItem('domanda_empresa');


var getUnit = function(){
    var idunidade = $routeParams.idunidade;
    console.log('idunidade ' + idunidade)
}
getUnit();
```

[image: print do console.log]

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que é porque voce injetou uma dependencia a menos na função. Então o que voce acha que é o `$routeParams` na verdade é o `$rootScope`.

Recomendo que você dê uma olhada no [styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection) do Angular.js feito pelo Jhon Papa.

Comment: Oi Leonardo.
Não, não fiz essa troca ou confusão.
Mas voltou a funcionar, dei um "command + R" e funcionou. Valeu

Comment: Ainda assim está errado o snippet que vc colocou aqui (pode ter sido typo ou algo assim).
Mas o array de strings para injeção tem esses argumentos na seguinte ordem `['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams']`
enquanto que a função do teu controller tem a seguinte `function ($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, $routeParams)`. Viu que falta o `$window` na sua função?

Comment: E isso faz diferença? A ordem e a falta do $window?

Comment: Faz sim, a ordem e a quantidade de itens que voce informa no Array deve ser a mesma na sua função. O Angularjs usa esse array de strings para procurar dentro dele onde que estão essas dependencias. Depois que ele as encontra ele pega sua função (controller) e chama ele passando todos as dependencias na ordem que foi informada. Por isso é importante manter a ordem que voce informa no array de dependencias e os argumentos da sua função/controller.

Comment: Valeu pela informação Leonardo!